# How do I get an NSAttributedString from an NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring, nsnumberformatter

I would like to use the methods:

`- setTextAttributesForPositiveValues:`

`- setTextAttributesForNegativeValues:`

Like this:

`[nf setTextAttributesForPositiveValues:@{[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.6 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]:NSForegroundColorAttributeName}];`

and

`[nf setTextAttributesForNegativeValues:@{[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.1 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]:NSForegroundColorAttributeName}];`

I am trying get the attributed text like this:

`NSAttributedString *str = [self.salaryFormatterColors attributedStringForObjectValue:@"Hi there" withDefaultAttributes:nil];`

But I am getting back nil.

How can I get back the attributed text?

Comment: Why would you expect to get anything meaningful back from a **number** formatter when you don't give it a number?

Comment: Ha, that's a good point.

Comment: @Paul.s I put in a @(30) rather than a string, and it isn't doing anything.  Is that what you meant by your comment?

Comment: Your dictionary literals have keys and values in the wrong order (it's different from the old NSDictionary class method). But fixing that probably won't help.

Answer (score 3):

Cracking open Hopper, it seems that the iOS `NSNumberFormatter` unconditionally returns `nil` from `-attributedStringForObjectValue:withDefaultAttributes:` as of iOS 9. I can't find any mention of this in the documentation, so that's helpful and probably worth a radar.

Your best bet is to subclass `NSNumberFormatter` and implement `-attributedStringForObjectValue:withDefaultAttributes:` yourself. The `NSFormatter` reference has some implementation suggestions:

> When implementing a subclass, return an NSAttributedString object if the string for display should have some attributes. For instance, you might want negative values in a financial application to appear in red text. Invoke your implementation of stringForObjectValue: to get the non-attributed string, then create an NSAttributedString object with it (see initWithString:). Use the attributes default dictionary to reset the attributes of the string when a change in value warrants it (for example, a negative value becomes positive)

And I suppose you could file a radar requesting implementation of this feature for iOS.

edit: I've gone ahead and implemented such a formatter in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nolanw/4cc88fac5c679156467929d04ea6d241).